# What's the seed used by random() if I don't initialize it with srandom()?

Tags: c, random

What's the seed used by C's `random()` if I don't initialize it with `srandom()`?
Is it system time?

Comment: Don't do it. If you don't seed it, `random()` will always produce the same sequence of "random" numbers.

Comment: Please, leave comment before downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another answer correctly states, `random()` is not in ISO *C*. It is, however, [in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/initstate.html), where the rule is analogous to ISO *C*'s `rand()`:

> Like `rand()`, `random()` shall produce by default a sequence of numbers that can be duplicated by calling `srandom()` with 1 as the seed.

Answer (score 5):

`random()` is not in standard C.

ISO C defines `rand()` and `srand()`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int rand(void);
void srand(unsigned int seed);
```

[The standard answers your question in section 7.22.2:](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#7.22.2)

> If `rand` is called before any calls to `srand` have been made, the same
>   sequence shall be generated as when `srand` is first called with a **seed
>   value of 1.**

Comment: Ah, the beauty of being able to read manuals. If everyone found out that this information was public, we wouldn't need Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

ISO C Random Number Functions You can check here that If you call rand before a seed has been established with srand, it uses the value 1 as a default seed.

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/ISO-Random.html